# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Unknown host

Tags: python, postgresql, debugging, psycopg2

I am unable to connect to the PostgreSQL database through psycopg2 for some reason

here is my connection configuration:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    user = "postgres",
    password = "xxxxxx",
    host = "xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    database = "current2",
    port = 5432
)
```

I put sensitive information in x's, but ignoring that, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That is an error with your domain name resolution (DNS) setup and has nothing to do with the database. The DNS server you have configured on your system cannot resolve the host name.

Either use a different DNS server, or use the database server's IP address.

Comment: I have the same issue inside a docker container - do you know how to fix it @LaurenzAlbe ?

Comment: Ok I found the solution: Inside the container a script would overwrite "/etc/resolv.conf" - I had to remove this and not it works flawlessly